# 一覧ページから詳細ページへデータを渡したい

Tags: javascript, php, monaca, html5, json

monaca.pushPageを使いデータを次のページへ渡したいです。
現状、jsonからデータを引張てきてそれをリスト表示させるところまではできているのですが、
for文内にある関数(showDetail)にjsonから取得したデータをいれ、それを次のページ(詳細ページ)に飛ばすところでつまずいております。

リンクを押しても画面が一瞬真っ白になった後、また一覧ページが表示されてしまって次のページへ進まなく困っています。

どなたかご教示いただけると幸いです。
何卒、よろしくお願い申し上げます。

↓一覧ページ↓

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      ons.bootstrap();

      document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
        //Ajax通信
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'http://○○○.jp/json.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(json) {
            var len = json.length;

            for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
              $("#list").append("<div>+ json[i].title + </div>");
              $("#list").append("<airtcle><div><a href='#' onClick='showDetail('" + json[i].movie_url + "', '" + json[i].title + "')'></a></div></article>");
            }
          },
          //下記を追加してどう言ったエラーが発生しているのか確認する
          error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // 省略
          }
        });
      }, false);

      //問題の箇所
      //jsonの読み込み完了後のfor文内にあるshowDetail()で引数を入れ下記の関数で次のdetail.htmlへデータを渡したいです。
      function showDetail(url, title) {
        monaca.pushPage("detail.html", {
          animation: 'lift',
          clearStack: false
        },
        {
          url: url,
          title: title
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator">
      <ons-page>
        <ons-toolbar>
          <div class="center"></div>
        </ons-toolbar>
        <section id="list"></section>
      </ons-page>
    </ons-navigator>
  </body>
</html>
```

↓詳細ページ↓

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.alert(JSON.stringify(monaca.queryParams));
      document.write("queryParams is" + JSON.stringify(monaca.queryParams));
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ons-page>
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left">
          <ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button>
        </div>
        <div class="center"></div>
      </ons-toolbar>
    </ons-page>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `AngularJS`を使えばすぐに解決できそうに思えますが、どうでしょうか？

Comment: @kazunoko 問題が解決したようで何よりです。僕は質問文を直しただけですので、AngularJSに関するコメントは oTak さんに返信されたほうが良いかと思われます。

Comment: @oTak
oTak様
この度はご教示誠にありがとうございます。 お恥ずかしながら、AngularJSの知識関しましては0に近い状態です。 AngularJSの知識があれば解決できるかもしれないのですね。 もう少し勉強してみます。

Comment: @Kazma Arakaki
Kazma Arakaki様
ご指摘ありがとうございます。
修正いたしました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

これでどうでしょう？
※検証のためにAjax部分はfor文にしています。

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script>
        ons.bootstrap();

        document.addEventListener('deviceready',function(){
            for(var i=1; i <= 10; i++) {
                $("#list").append('<airtcle><div><a href="#" onClick="showDetail(\'URL:' + i + '\', \'TITLE:' + i + '\')">' + i + '</a></div></article>');
            }
        },false);

        function showDetail(url, title) {
            // detail.htmlに遷移
            // http://ja.onsen.io/guide/overview.html#navigatorgetCurrentPage
            myNavigator.pushPage("detail.html",{
                animation: 'lift', 
                url : url, // 渡すデータ
                title : title,  // 渡すデータ
            })
        }

        // detail.htmlのページ初期化のイベント
        // http://ja.onsen.io/guide/overview.html#Pageinitevent
        document.addEventListener("pageinit", function(e) {
            if (e.target.id == "page-detail") {
                // 渡したデータを取得して表示
                // http://ja.onsen.io/guide/overview.html#navigatorgetCurrentPage
                var options = myNavigator.getCurrentPage().options;
                $('#page-detail').find('.url').text(options.url);
                $('#page-detail').find('.title').text(options.title);
            }
        }, false);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator">
    <ons-page>
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="center">Index</div>
        </ons-toolbar>
        <section id="list"></section>
    </ons-page>
</ons-navigator>
</body>
```

**detail.html**

```
<ons-page id="page-detail">
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="left">
        <ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button>
      </div>
      <div class="center">Detail</div>
    </ons-toolbar>

    <div id="contents">
        <p>URL：<span class="url"></span></p>
        <p>TITLE：<span class="title"></span></p>
    </div>
</ons-page>
```

Comment: nikke様
この度はご教示ありがとうございます。
ご教示いただいた結果、無事詳細ページへ飛ぶことができました。
本当にありがとうございました。